# Recursive yield method to traverse object graph and return visited nodes

Tags: c#, recursion, extension-methods, yield-return

I'm trying to write an extension method that is supposed to traverse an object graph and return all visited objects.

I'm not sure if my approach is the best, so please do comment on that. Also yield is frying my brain... I'm sure the answer is obvious :/

**Model**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass Parent {get;set;}
}
```

**Method**

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectNested<T>
    (this T source, Func<T, T> selector)
    where T : class
{
    yield return source;
    var parent = selector(source);
    if (parent == null)
        yield break;
    yield return SelectNestedParents(parent, selector).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var list = myObject.SelectNested(x => x.Parent);
```

**The problem**

It's almost working. But it only visits 2 objects. It self and the parent.

So given this graph `c -> b -> a` starting from `c`. `c, b` is returned which is not quite what I wanted.

The result I'm looking for is `b, c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last line of `SelectNested` you only return the first parent:

```
yield return SelectNestedParents(parent, selector).FirstOrDefault();
```

You have to return all parents:

```
foreach (var p in SelectNestedParents(parent, selector))
  return p;
```

Instead of using recursion you can use iteration which probably is more efficient:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectNested<T>(this T source, Func<T, T> selector)
  where T : class {
  var current = source;
  while (current != null) {
    yield return current;
    current = selector(current);
  }
}
```

Comment: I like the non-recursive approach. But it should be `var current = selector(source);` instead to satisfy my needs. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Snæbjørn From your original post, your method always returns `source` first unmodified.  The code provided here does the same thing.  By initializing `current` to `source`, it makes the code simpler by eliminating the `yield return source` line.

Comment: That's correct. However the only reason `yield return source` was there was because it was a recursive function. The result I really was looking was without the initial object. As I tried to explain on the last line of the post :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work as expected:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectNested<T>()
{
    if (source != null){
        yield return source;

        var parent = selector(source);

        // Result of the recursive call is IEnumerable<T>
        // so you need to iterate over it and return its content.
        foreach (var parent in (SelectNested(selector(source))))
        {
            yield return parent;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, your class looks to be a list, not a graph, since `selector` returns only one object not an enumeration of them.  Thus recursion is not necessary.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectNested<T>(this T source, Func<T, T> selector)
        where T : class
    {
        while (source != null)
        {
            yield return source;
            source = selector(source);
        }
    }
```